# Fill out an array of a fixed length with the same values

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I want to initialize array like this

$my_arr = array(1,1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1,1);

Is there any better way to set up twenty ones for php array?

The way to use `for i=0 ... to 19` would take at least 3 strings so I don't think that's a better option.

Thank you.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, use [`array_fill()`](http://php.net/array_fill):

```
$my_arr = array_fill( 0, 20, 1);
```

Now, `$my_arr` has 20 entries, from indexes 0 to 19, with the value 1.

Answer (score 2):

Use `array_fill` function

`$arr = array_fill(0, 20, 1);`